# How to convert statement with the existential quantifier to statement with universal quantifier?

Tags: first-order-logic

How to convert the following statement with the existential quantifier to statement with universal quantifier?

$\exists n. n>1\rightarrow x(n)\not=1$

Please give me some suggestion?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "with universal quantifier". Generally  you can not convert a "universal formula" to an "existential formula" (there are no $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ where $\exists x; Q(x) \equiv \forall x; P(x)$ in the same semantics). But I guess [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Negation) will help you, a basic property of quantifiers which asserts that the negation of some universally quantified formula equals to the existential quantification of its negation. Then you just need a double negation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's give names for the atom formulas:

$n>1$ will be $\phi$ and $x(n) \neq 1$ will be $\psi$
Now what we have is:
$$\exists{n} (\phi\rightarrow\psi)$$
$$\exists{n} (\neg\phi \lor\psi)$$
$$\neg\neg \exists{n} (\neg\phi \lor\psi)$$
$$\neg\forall{n} \neg(\neg\phi \lor\psi)$$
$$\neg\forall{n} (\phi \land \neg\psi)$$
$$\neg\forall{n}((n>1) \land \neg(x(n)\neq 1))$$
$$\neg\forall{n}((n>1) \land (x(n) = 1))$$